Error on AuditModule during Alfresco startup
I'm upgrading an Alfresco CE 5.x to 7.4.2. It has the AuditModule enabled in the properties but now, after the upgrade, I receive this error when Alfresco boots up:
2024-11-14T17:52:57,305 [] ERROR [audit.model.AuditModelRegistryImpl] [main] Failed to load audit model: jar:file:/opt/alfresco-cdr/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-21.14.jar!/alfresco/audit/alfresco-audit-access.xml
org.alfresco.repo.audit.model.AuditModelException: 10140000 Audit application key 'alfresco-access' is used by: AuditApplication[ name=alfresco-access, id=2, disabledPathsId=3094]
        at org.alfresco.repo.audit.model.AuditModelRegistryImpl$AuditModelRegistryState.cacheAuditElements(AuditModelRegistryImpl.java:646) ~[alfresco-repository-20.164.jar:20.164]
.....
2024-11-14T17:52:57,314 [] ERROR [audit.model.AuditModelRegistryImpl] [main] Failed to load audit model: jar:file:/opt/alfresco-cdr/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-21.14.jar!/alfresco/audit/alfresco-audit-tagging.xml
org.alfresco.repo.audit.model.AuditModelException: 10140001 Audit application key 'tagging' is used by: AuditApplication[ name=Alfresco Tagging Service, id=1, disabledPathsId=2]
        at org.alfresco.repo.audit.model.AuditModelRegistryImpl$AuditModelRegistryState.cacheAuditElements(AuditModelRegistryImpl.java:646) ~[alfresco-repository-20.164.jar:20.164]
.....

this are the properties on alfresco-global.properties
# Enable the alfresco-access audit application

audit.alfresco-access.enabled=true
audit.cdr-audit.enabled=true
audit.cdr-audit.sub-actions.enabled=true
audit.cdr-audit.sub-events.enabled=true
audit.filter.cdr-audit.transaction.type=cm:content;st:site;cm:folder;cm:person;

# Audit map filter for AccessAuditor - restricts recorded events to user driven events
audit.filter.alfresco-access.default.enabled=false
audit.filter.alfresco-access.transaction.user=.*
audit.filter.alfresco-access.transaction.path=~/sys:archivedItem;~/ver:;/app:company_home/st:sites/.*
audit.filter.alfresco-access.transaction.type=cm:content;cm:folder;st:site;cm:person

Can anyone help me finding out what is the problem? I'm thinking about there is something wrong in my DB

Found it!
The problem is both 'alfresco-access' and 'tagging' keys are being duplicated and you cannot such situation. Both files are core ones, inside alfresco standard libs.
So I found It had a duplicated library, alfresco-repository-20.X and alfresco-repository-21.Y added with amps and customization to the Alfresco Installation.
I removed the oldest one and the error disappeared

Ouch - the alfresco repository libs should not appear in any amp/extension!
